# Could we add some internet related tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I know this site is primarily about music theory, but in our present day and age, much of this is taught and learned online or through the use of technology.

Could we have some tags added that are similar to the following: music-blog, music-site, music-ebook, mp3, ogg, midi, music-tutorial, music-video, online-theory, etc?  It would be nice to have some of these tags or something similar for questions related to theory as it relates to and interacts with technology and the web.

Comment: The medium of the content really shouldn't detriment what tags to use. The content itself should be much more influential.

Answer (score 6):

Tags come as needed, not before - so we don't need to create an mp3 tag, for example, unless we need it.

We are unlikely to ever need online-theory, music-tutorial, music-video, music-ebook, music-site or music-blog as they would add nothing to a question. Why would we separate out online theory (whatever that is) from [theory](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theory)? It doesn't matter where we get documentation, in many cases.

Additionally, mp3, ogg, midi have nothing to do with the internet.

Also - [midi](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/midi) already exists.

Comment: I actually asked a question last night looking for ebook and mp3 tags.  I saw no internet/technology tags available at all.  I just know there is an such an integration of theory and technology/web that I think there does need to be some type of identifier when talking about something specifically web or it related.

Comment: That question has no need of eBook or mp3 tags. They do not help the question. In reality that question is almost off topic, as it is a recommendation/opinion question